# AutoMapper mapping Many to one Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper, asp.net-apicontroller

I am attempting to map my Person model to my PersonDto class to be used in my api controller.

Person has a many to one relationship between Person and TaskItem.

**Person**

```
 public class Person
    {
        public Person() 
        {
            TaskItems = new HashSet<TaskItem>();
        }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Monday { get; set; }
        public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
        public bool Wednesday { get; set;}
        public bool Thursday { get; set;}
        public bool Friday { get; set;}
        public bool Saturday { get; set;}
        public bool Sunday { get; set;}

        public ICollection<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set;}
      

       
    }
```

**PersonDto**

```
public class PersonDto
    {
       
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Monday { get; set; }
        public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
        public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
        public bool Thursday { get; set; }
        public bool Friday { get; set; }
        public bool Saturday { get; set; }
        public bool Sunday { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }
    }
```

**TaskItemDto**

```
 public class TaskItemDto
    {
        public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public TimeOfDay? TimeOfDay { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public int DayId { get; set; }
        public Day Day { get; set; }
    }
```

**TaskItem**

```
 public class TaskItem
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public TimeOfDay? TimeOfDay { get; set; }
        public int DayId { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }


        public Day Day { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }                     

    }
```

**PersonProfile**

```
public class PersonProfile : Profile
    {
        public PersonProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>().ForMember(m => m.TaskItems, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.TaskItems.Select(e => e.PersonId)));
            CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>();
        }
    }
```

**AutoMapper and Json configuration**

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;

});
```

**ApiController**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PeopleApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TaskDelegatingWebAppContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public PeopleApiController(TaskDelegatingWebAppContext context, IMapper mapper) 
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // GET /api/people
        public IEnumerable<PersonDto> GetPeople()
        {




            return _context.Person.Include(e => e.TaskItems).ToList().Select(_mapper.Map<Person, PersonDto>);

        }

        // Get /api/person/1
        [Route("api/[controller]/GetPerson={id}")]
        public Person GetPerson(int id)
        {
            var person = _context.Person.SingleOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == id);

            if (person == null)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound.ToString());
            }
            return person;

        }


        // POST /api/person/1
        [Route("api/[controller]/CreatePerson")]
        [HttpPost]
        public Person CreatePerson(Person person)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            
                throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString());
            
            _context.Person.Add(person);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return person;
        }


        // PUT /api/person/1

        [Route("api/[controller]/UpdatePerson={id}")]
        public void UpdatePerson(int id, Person person)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.ToString());
            var personInDb = _context.Person.SingleOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == id);

            if (personInDb == null)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound.ToString());
            }
            

            personInDb.Name = person.Name;
            personInDb.Email = person.Email;
            personInDb.Saturday = person.Saturday;
            personInDb.Monday = person.Monday;
            personInDb.Tuesday= person.Tuesday;
            personInDb.Wednesday= person.Wednesday;
            personInDb.Thursday = person.Thursday;
            personInDb.Friday = person.Friday;
            personInDb.Sunday= person.Sunday;
            personInDb.TaskItems = person.TaskItems.Where(e => e.PersonId == id).ToList();
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // DELETE /api/customers/1
        [Route("api/[controller]/Delete={id}")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeletePerson(int id)
        {
            var personInDb = _context.Person.SingleOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == id);
            if (personInDb == null)
                throw new Exception (HttpStatusCode.NotFound.ToString());

            _context.Person.Remove(personInDb);
        }


    }
```

When I go to the https://localhost:7148/api/peopleapi I get

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or > unsupported mapping.

> Mapping types:
> Int32 -> TaskItem
> System.Int32 -> TaskDelegatingWebApp.Models.TaskItem
> lambda_method138(Closure , int , TaskItem , ResolutionContext )

> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

> Mapping types:
> Person -> PersonDto
> TaskDelegatingWebApp.Models.Person -> TaskDelegatingWebApp.Dtos.PersonDto

> Type Map configuration:
> Person -> PersonDto
> TaskDelegatingWebApp.Models.Person -> TaskDelegatingWebApp.Dtos.PersonDto

> Destination Member:
> TaskItems
> lambda_method136(Closure , Person , PersonDto , ResolutionContext )

I have been able to pull the Person data, but not the related TaskItems.

[Example of old GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZHLe.png)

Answer (score 0):

in PersonProfile
change

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
    .ForMember(m => m.TaskItems, 
        o => o.MapFrom(e => e.TaskItems.Select(e => e.PersonId)));
CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>();
```

to

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
    .ForMember(m => m.TaskItems, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.TaskItems))
    .ReverseMap();
```